# How do you calculate the pH of 0.01 M H2S solution (hydrogen sulfide, an amphiprotic acid)?

Tags: physical-chemistry, ph

I found a question in a physical chemistry book

> What is the pH of $\pu{0.01 M}$ $\ce{H2S}$ solution? Given, $K_\mathrm {a_1} = 9×10^{-8}$ and $K_\mathrm{a_2} = 1.2×10^{-13}$.

I thought of applying the following formula,

$$\mathrm{pH} =\frac{\mathrm pK_\mathrm{a_1} + \mathrm pK_\mathrm {a_2}}{2}$$

However, I got confused by another formula which states

$$\ce{[H+]} = \sqrt{(K_\mathrm{a_1}× C + K_\mathrm{a_2}×C)}$$

Which formula should I use and how do I approach this type of question?

Comment: There is a lot of available online material about pH computation, including but not limited to this site and chem.libretexts.org. Be sure you have done proper review. // You can also derive the formula, using equations for inventory and equilibrium constants.

Comment: Convenient reference for text/formula formatting:
 [Notation basics](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation)  /  [Formatting of math/chem expressions](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here)  /  
[upright vs italic](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/443/which-symbols-are-written-in-roman-upright-font-and-which-are-italicized)  // [For more:  Math SE MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).  // Keep CH SE Q titles in plain text.

Comment: I am asking about how do I determine which formula to use

Comment: Do not  use formulas like "black boxes" without understanding. Learn basics by studying, e.g. searching of *pH polyprotic acids* .  Asking should be used when other ways failed, to fill remaining gaps, not to lay foundations. // For this particular case, the 2nd ionization can be safely ignored and pH can be calculated like for monoprotic acid.

Comment: Note that the simplified formula [H+]=sqrt(Ka.c) for pH of monoprotic acid assumes [H2S]>>[HS-]=[H+]. Check, if deviations are acceptable, before accepting the result. Otherwise, in the worst case none of relations fits, you would have to use the general equation derived from the 2 equilibrium (acid, water) and 2 inventory (acid forms, charge) equations.

Answer (score 2):

$\ce{H2S}$ is not an amphiprotic acid, it is a diprotic acid (meaning it can donate two protons rather than one). You could say e.g. dihydrogen phosphate is an amphiprotic acid because it can either donate (up to two) or accept protons.

The easiest way to deal with this is to ignore the second proton, calculate the pH using the first equilibrium, and compare the pH with the p$K_\mathrm{a}$ to check if there is appreciable dissociation of the second proton.

The second dissociation constant is disputed [[1](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.niox.2013.07.001)], but because the pH will be acidic, you can neglect dissociation of the second proton. It will have negligible effect on the pH.

#### Reference

Li, Q.; Lancaster, J. R. Chemical Foundations of Hydrogen Sulfide Biology. *Nitric Oxide* **2013**, 0, [10.1016/j.niox.2013.07.001](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.niox.2013.07.001)